# Ohms law, resistance calculation

Tags: resistors, components, ohms-law

I'm new to electronics and I don't understand why you subtract source voltage by the components recommended voltage, but you just divide by the recommended amps...
Why don't you subtract source amps by recommended amps also?
I may have something totally wrong - like I said im new, but I cannot find this anywhere online... thank you!

Comment: "subtract source voltage by the components recommended voltage, but you just divide by the recommended amps"  -- this is in the context of solving one *specific* problem, but you have not given us the context. Without that context, we are not really able to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: If I have a 9volt 6amp battery and a led that requires 2volts and .02amps, why do I only subtract 9-2volts and not 6-.02amps also....

Comment: Please edit your question to include the information needed to answer it.

Comment: @ThePhoton All I'm asking is why you dont subtract source amps by forward amps on the bottom of the resistence formula?

Comment: I'm asking you to edit your question to give all the information, instead of putting it in comments. Your question should be complete without reading the comments and the mods might delete these comments at any time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I have a 9volt 6amp battery and a led that requires 2volts and .02amps, why do I only subtract 9-2volts and not 6-.02amps also

The context you are discussing is finding the proper series resistance for an LED (it's important to specify the context, because electronics is certainly not all about attaching LEDs to batteries with a resistor). It boils down to the fact that we have a circuit with a few elements in *series*: voltages *add* going around the loop, while the same current is seen in all elements.

The reason why we consider the voltage of the battery, and not its current, is because a battery is effectively modeled as a voltage source. The noun phrase "9volt 6amp battery" refers to a battery which outputs a roughly constant 9 volts, and can source up to 6 amperes before exceeding its rating (which leads to voltage drop, overheating, and so on). We also model the LED as a device of constant voltage drop:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fek12I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are two important laws of circuit analysis that we consider here:

1. KCL - All current which enters a node must leave it (or equivalently here, the current is the same throughout a loop)
2. KVL - The total voltage drop around a loop must be zero.

KCL tells us that the current is the same everywhere within our loop. At our desired operating point, the LED, resistor, and battery all experience a 0.02 Ampere current.

Now, KVL tells us that the total voltage drop around the loop must be equal to zero.

Let's set up the equation: \$9\,[\text{V}] - 0.02\,[\text{A}]\cdot R - 2\,[\text{V}] = 0\$.

This comes from the branch constituent equations for each component. The battery's voltage is 9 V, the resistor's drop is given by \$V = IR\$, and the LED's voltage drop is 2 V when lit up and operating properly.

These are all approximations that are good enough for our analysis. If we needed extreme accuracy, or were solving this with the aid of a computer, we could use a more accurate model for our components which model *small* variations in voltage as the battery and LED currents vary.

If we rearrange the equation, we get: \$R = \frac{9\,[\text{V}] - 2\,[\text{V}]}{0.02\,[\text{A}]}\$ which is consistent with the technique you were using.

Furthermore, you will be able to conclude that this shorthand technique you are using is *only* appropriate for this specific circuit topology. For any other circuit problem, you will need to through the steps of solving appropriate equations just like I demonstrated here.

Comment: Very informational and much appreciated! Electronics are wildly complex right now to me and I dont even know what questions to ask sometimes! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @TheAdmin Not a problem, happy to help!